# Is it possible for javascript to break IIFE from another function?

Tags: javascript

Please see this example code:

```js
(function() {
  if (1 + 1 === 2) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(`This Line Won't Compile`);
})()
```

The code above simply breaks when the condition is true.

However, I would like to extract the whole logic outside of this IIFE.

```js
function checkNumber() {
  if (1 + 1 === 2) {
    return;
  }
}

(function() {
  checkNumber(); // How do I achieve this?

  console.log(`This Line Now Compile, but I don't want this line compile.`);
})()
```

How do I achieve this?

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean "when the condition is true"? There is no overloading that lets 1+1 not be 2 in JavaScript. Also, JavaScript doesn't get "compiled", so I don't even understand why you're trying to do what you think you want to do. Why would you need unreachable code at all?

Comment: `if (1 + 1 === 2) {...`  ??? In what universe is this condition false???

Comment: @zer00ne, it is just symbolic check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a flag if the function take short circuit. In this case you need another check and return early.

```js
function checkNumber() {
    if (1 + 1 === 2) {
        return true;           // supply a flag
    }
}

void function() {
    console.log('IIFE');
    if (checkNumber()) return; // use this flag

    console.log(`This Line Now Compile, but I don't want this line compile.`);
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, a simple one would be to set a global variable which you can then use in the IIFE

```js
var iAmAGlobalVariableKnowingWhatToDo = false;

var checkNumber = function () {
  if (1 + 1 === 2) {
      iAmAGlobalVariableKnowingWhatToDo = true;
      return;
  }
  
  iAmAGlobalVariableKnowingWhatToDo = false;

};

// note everything until this line of code is in the global scope!
// that's why you can use the checkNumber() and the variable inside the IIFE

(function() {
  checkNumber();
  
  if(iAmAGlobalVariableKnowingWhatToDo) {
      return;
  }

  console.log(`This Line Now Compile, but I don't want this line compile.`);
})()
```